# Reading in a .xls file with Apache POI 3.7

Tags: apache-poi

I am trying to read in a .xls file in an effort to interrogate its contents. 
I keep getting an AssertionError. Also I want to delete this file from the directory after the test.

@Test
    public void testSpreadsheetCont() throws Exception {

```
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:/var/fedex/pricingbackfillmonitor/data/Backfill Message Monitor.xls");
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
    HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.getRow(2);
    HSSFCell cell1 = row1.getCell(1);
    boolean success = false;
    if (cell1.getStringCellValue() == "L")
        {
        success = true;
        }else{
            success = false;
        }
    Assert.assertTrue(success);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing Strings for equality, use the equals() method. So, change

```
if (cell1.getStringCellValue() == "L")
```

to

```
if ("L".equals(cell1.getStringCellValue()))
```